# Using a specialization of variadic template as a template argument

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, template-specialization

Consider the following:

```
template <class...>
struct MyT;

template <class T>
struct MyT<T> {};

template <template <class> class TT = MyT> struct A {}; // fine

using B = A<MyT>; // does not compile

int main() {
  return 0;
}
```

When `MyT` is used as a default argument of `A`, the compiler (g++ 5.4.0) is happy. However, when it is used to instantiate `A`, the story is different:

```
temp.cpp:19:16: error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<template<class> class TT> struct A’
 using B = A<MyT>;
                ^
temp.cpp:19:16: note:   expected a template of type ‘template<class> class TT’, got ‘template<class ...> struct MyT’
```

I can fix it by introducing an alias:

```
template <class T>
using MyTT = MyT<T>;

using B = A<MyTT>; // fine
```

The question: what is the reason for the error and is there a solution without introducing an alias?

**EDIT** Please note that `A` is declared to have a template template parameter as shown and that is not given for change.

Comment: Use `template <template <class...> class TT = MyT> struct A {};`. Specializations are not taken in account in this case, thus definitions differ.

Comment: @skypjack The declaration of `A` is a given. I should have stated this.

Comment: Then you should define a template class or an alias declaration that expects exactly one parameter.

Comment: When B is not templated, how can you ever actually instantiate MyT? Your `struct A` is basically pointless; why accept a template parameter at all if you cannot even use it?

Comment: @skypjack How come the compiler accepted `MyT` as a default argument just fine?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning It is not. Try to use it directly.

Comment: @AndyG The actual application is much more complicated, having to do with a script substituting undefined pre-processor symbols after pre-processing. I agree that this may look pointless in the simple example. However, the example suffices for the question asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that and you cannot use such a type as a default parameter. The fact that it seems to be *accepted* as long as you don't rely on it doesn't mean that the default parameter is a valid one.
Consider the following code that explicitly uses the default type:

```
template <class...>
struct MyT;

template <class T>
struct MyT<T> {};

template <template <class> class TT = MyT> struct A {}; // fine

int main() {
  A<> a;
  return 0;
}
```

The error is quite clear:

> template template argument has different template parameters than its corresponding template template parameter

Partial specializations are not taken in account in this case, thus the two declarations differ.
You should either declare `A` as:

```
template <template <class...> class TT = MyT> struct A;
```

Or declare somewhere a type that is constrained to a single argument, as an example by means of an using declaration as you did.

Comment: How come the compiler did not check the suitability of `MyT` for being a default argument? I think the compiler usually performs such checks before instantiating templates...

Comment: Not sure if it's mandatory from the point of view of the standard or if it's an UB. I would say that it's valid, for both the major compilers do that, but let's wait for someone more skilled than me to explain it in _standardese_. :-)

Answer (score 1):

First, the default argument doesn't work either.

Second, template template arguements are a strange beast.  It would make sense if a template template argument would take anything that could be instantiated with the signature described in the template template argument.

That is not how it works.

Instead it works the other way around.

```
template<template<class...>class Z> struct foo {};
template<template<class   >class Z> struct bar {};

template<class...>struct a{};
template<class   >struct b{};
```

`foo` will accept `a` *or* `b`.

`bar` will accept *only `b`*.

The correct response to this, once you understand it, is "what the hell?".  If you aren't responding "what the hell" back up and see if you can understand it.  This basically works backwards from typical typing for arguements in C++; it behaves more like a return type than an argument.  (Learn the terms contravariance and covariance if you want to see some of the language that lets you talk about this directly)

This is quite non-intuitive, and why it works this way exactly would involve tracking down the pre-history of C++.

But, as a benefit, a `template<class...>class` argument is in effect an "any template that only takes type parameters".  I find this highly useful.

As a downside, `template<class>class` arguements are almost completely useless.

Tl;dr: make your `template<template` parameters be `template<template<class...>class`, and metaprogram only with templates that only take types.  If you have a template that takes values, write a type wrapper that replaces a requirement for a `std::size_t X` with a `std::integral_constant< std::size_t, X >`.

Answer (score 0):

Forgetting for a moment the question of "Why would you do this?", 
the first version would work if you hadn't done any template specialization.

```
template <class T>
struct MyT {  };

template <template <class> class TT = MyT> struct A 
{};

using B = A<MyT>;
```

With template specialization, the compiler must determine the best match, but since you haven't ever actually provided any template arguments it's ambiguous.

When you introduce `MyTT` you are using a single template argument, and the compiler is smart enough to see that you have a specialization when there is only one arg:

```
template <class T>
using MyTT = MyT<T>;
```

It chooses the specialization instead of the variadic version in this case.

But now we circle back to the grand question... why? Unless within `A` you're always instantiating `MyT` with a specific class, it's pointless to use `A` at all:

```
template<template<class> class TT = MyT> struct A
{
   // use an instance of TT??
   TT<int> myInstance; // forced to choose `int`
};
```

Comment: It doesn't work if you don't provide specializations **and** you use a variadic template. Look out, you have actually wiped out the primary template and used the specialization having a single parameter in your example. This way it works because it's right, that's all.

Comment: The compiler is smart enough to see that `MyTT` is a template, but is not smart enough to see that the template parameter of `A` is a template? What is the difference?

Comment: @skypjack: That's what I meant to imply; in a situation where there was only the single-template struct it would work. I wanted to segue into why OP was able to make it work when there was a primary variadic template.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to split your question into 2 parts.

A) Consider the template of your structure is simpler

```
template <class T>
  struct TestStruct {
};

template <
  template <class>
  class TT = TestStruct
>
struct A
{
  int a; // sorry to modify this. This help to show how it works
};

int main() {
  A< TestStruct > b;
  b.a; // it works!
  return 0;
}
```

It works because of the template class TT only accept the template with < class... > template. The specializated class is not count on this ( because the underlying of it is still template < class ... > )

B) even you update your struct A to the template< class... > one, you still have one more problem. What is the template argument of TT? Please see the example below

```
template <class...>                                                                                                                 
struct MyT;                                                                                                                         

template <class T>                                                                                                                  
struct MyT<T> {                                                                                                                     
    int a;                                                                                                                          
};                                                                                                                                  

template <                                                                                                                          
    template <class...>                                                                                                             
    class TT = MyT
    // may be you need to add some more typename here, such as
    // typename T1, ... , and then TT<T1> a;                                                                                                                 
>                                                                                                                                   
struct A                                                                                                                            
{                                                                                                                                   
    TT<int> a; 
    // Here ! TT is a template only, do not have the template parameters!!!                                                                                                                   
};                                                                                                                                  

int main() {                                                                                                                        

  A< MyT > b;                                                                                                                                        
  b.a;     // it works!!                                                                                                                         

  return 0;                                                                                                                         
}
```

But, if you really cannot update the signature of those definitions, you can do a proxy class

```
template< class T >
struct Proxy : MyT<T>
{
};
```